# Kotlin difference between two LocalDateTime

Tags: kotlin, datetime, date-difference, kotlinx-datetime

I have two `kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime` instances:

```
val startDate =
LocalDateTime(year = 2020, month = Month.MARCH, dayOfMonth = 25, hour = 10, minute = 
36, second = 12)
val endDate =
LocalDateTime(year = 2023, month = Month.FEBRUARY, dayOfMonth = 28, hour = 0, minute 
= 0, second = 1)
```

I want to compute difference between these two dates but I don't want to use Java way.
how can I achive this ?
by the way I'm doing micro optimization so I can't convert those to `Instant` to use `Instant.until()`.

Comment: you mightbe able to convert both `LocalDateTime`s to `Instant`s and then use [`Instant.until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/until.html).

Comment: So you are after a [`kotlin.time.Duration`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/)? Or a [`DateTimePeriod`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/-date-time-period/)?

Comment: @dan1st I kind of have to do micro optimization. converting in anything is not good for me

Comment: *The arithmetic on LocalDateTime values is not provided, since without accounting for the time zone transitions it may give misleading results.* (from the class documentation). So as @dan1st said, please convert to `Instant` objects first.

Comment: *I kind of have to do micro optimization. converting in anything is not good for me* This seems to be an important piece of information. Please add it to the question proper.

Comment: If you are doing micro-optimizations, is that part really the bottleneck? And what are you using for benchmarking? JMH? What exactly are you optimizing? Throughput? Also, do you need to use `kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime` in the first place?

Comment: After four days you still have not received an answer to your question. My guess is that folks have found your requirements contradictory and answering impossible. I could be wrong.

Comment: @OleV.V. Or it may be that [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime), as a relatively new library, has not gained many users yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Non-Java

I do not yet know Kotlin, but I can read [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/).

The [`LocalDateTime`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/-local-date-time/) class represents a date with time-of-day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this class cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline.

In contrast, the [`Instant`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/-instant/) class does represent a moment, a point on the timeline. This class represent a date with time-of-day as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

You can get the amount of time elapsed between two `Instant` objects in the `DateTimePeriod` class. No such class for `LocalDateTime`.

So we should be able to assign a zero offset to turn our `LocalDateDate` objects into `Instant` objects. I do not know how to do this exactly, as I don't use Kotlin. But I imagine you can make a [`UtcOffset`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/-utc-offset.html) by passing zero in all three arguments, then apply that to your `LocalDateTime` to wind your way to an `Instant`.

In your Question, you were reluctant to go this route because of "micro optimization". I have no idea what you meant. But that route is the one I would choose. Otherwise, you will need write your own implementation to calculated elapsed time.

## Java

[*kotlinx-datetime*](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime) is a library that imitates the *java.time* framework bundled with Java, but contains only a limited subset of the functionality. This library is for Kotlin apps that will *not* be deployed to a JVM.

In your case, the missing piece you need is the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class in the *java.time* classes.

If your app will be deployed to a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), use *java.time*: `Duration.between( startLdt , endLdt )`.

```java
Duration d = 
    Duration.between( 
        LocalDateTime.of ( 2020, Month.MARCH, 25, 10, 36, 12 ) ,
        LocalDateTime.of ( 2023, Month.FEBRUARY, 28, 0, 0, 1 )
    ) ;
```